# How to capture screenshot on test case failure with PyTest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Currently I am using the following solution to take a screenshot in the end of every test function with PyTest. How can I make sure that the screenshots are taken only in case if a test fails? This is a question about PyTest mechanics. This question is NOT about selenium or appium.

I found similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but not exactly the same. Solutions provided to those other questions do not answer my question. Since taking a screenshot on a test failure with PyTest is a common problem, I believe that it deserves a separate and a quite specific answer.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def take_screenshot(self, appium_driver):
    yield
    time.sleep(1)
    current_filename_clean = os.path.basename(__file__).replace("test_", "").replace(".py", "")
    current_test_name = os.environ.get("PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST").split(":")[-1].split(" ")[0].replace("test_", "")
    appium_driver.get_screenshot_as_file(
        f'test_reports/{current_filename_clean}_android_{current_test_name}_{datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}.png')
```

Comment: This is a fairly popular topic that has several mentions in the docs. Fixture example: [Making test result information available in fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures), hook example: [post-process test reports / failures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures).

Comment: I found those articles, however, the solution there is not so strightforward for my problem. I believe, since this is a fairly common problem, its better to devote to it a specific and to the point answer and kinda best practicies catalgue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the full solution for your `conftest.py` file for running it headless in a docker container:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime    
import pytest
import os
from selenium import webdriver as selenium_webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# set up webdriver fixture
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def selenium_driver(request):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    driver = selenium_webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    yield driver
    driver.quit()

# set up a hook to be able to check if a test has failed
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    # set a report attribute for each phase of a call, which can
    # be "setup", "call", "teardown"

    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)

# check if a test has failed
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def test_failed_check(request):
    yield
    # request.node is an "item" because we use the default
    # "function" scope
    if request.node.rep_setup.failed:
        print("setting up a test failed!", request.node.nodeid)
    elif request.node.rep_setup.passed:
        if request.node.rep_call.failed:
            driver = request.node.funcargs['selenium_driver']
            take_screenshot(driver, request.node.nodeid)
            print("executing test failed", request.node.nodeid)

# make a screenshot with a name of the test, date and time
def take_screenshot(driver, nodeid):
    time.sleep(1)
    file_name = f'{nodeid}_{datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M")}.png'.replace("/","_").replace("::","__")
    driver.save_screenshot(file_name)
```

Comment: In my case, I needed to replace @pytest.fixture(scope='session') with @pytest.fixture(scope='module'), to recreate a driver if multiple tests are called. The reset of the code works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: what If I want to send the screenshot url to actual report?

Comment: It didn't work for me at first, so a few notes to future readers. 1. This code have to be defined in a file named exactly `conftest.py`, otherwise you'll get an error `AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'rep_setup'`. 2. if it fails with `KeyError: 'selenium_driver'`, that means that tests you created didn't use the fixture defined in the code as `selenium_driver`. IOW, a test have to accept a parameter named `selenium_driver`.

Comment: @OstapDidenko any reason you have `sleep(1)` in the code? Should it be perhaps removed?

Answer (score 2):

There is another way, similar to the one by @Ostap: using `pytest_runtest_makereport` ([docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures), [API reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html)) postprocessing capabilities. Just a bit simpler:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    if rep.when == 'call' and rep.failed:
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        driver.save_screenshot(f".\\Screenshots\\fail_{now}.png")
```

Comment: it seems like this way the screenshot filename won't contain name of the test on which it was taken. That may be a problem when trying to identify to which of the tests that screenshot refers,

Comment: @OstapDidenko That is easily remedied with `driver.save_screenshot(f"fail_{item.name}{now}.png")`

Answer (score 0):

it works only with scope='session'
If u need scope='function' it can help u:
with allure, if u need

```
  @pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
  def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
      outcome = yield
      rep = outcome.get_result()
      if rep.when == 'call' and rep.failed:
          if 'browser' in item.fixturenames:
              web_driver = item.funcargs['browser']
      else:
          print('Fail to take screen-shot')
          return
      file_name = f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S_%F')}"\
        .replace("/", "_").replace("::", "__")
      capture_path = (f"./screenshots/{file_name}.png")
      web_driver.save_screenshot(capture_path)
      allure.attach(
        web_driver.get_screenshot_as_png(),
        name=f'screenshot {file_name}',
        attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG
      )
```